# custom cordova pushNotification wrapper returning observable

Tags: angular, typescript, callback, rxjs, observable

the phonegap-plugin-push for cordova has several functions with the following syntax

```
function name(successCallback(),errorCallback(),options)
```

I want to write a wrapper function and return an Observable but I'm a little stuck on how to create it using typescript for angular2.

so

```
name.subscribe((data)=>{...},(err)=>{})
```

So far I've mostly only subscribed to existing observable like http.

so it should look like

```
public unregister(options):Observable<any>{
  if(window.PushNotification){
    window.PushNotification.ungregister(...)
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: It seems that you can already unregister push notifications. What are you hoping to accomplish by wrapping it in an observable? Knowing you intention will help provide a solution.

Comment: the unregsiter was just an example, I'm generally interested in how to achieve it :)

in my particular use case, I'm trying to build a library which basically wraps the given methodes and return observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new `Observable` using `create` or directly with the constructor.

```
//Higher order function for binding a cordova style method to a method 
//that returns Observables
function bindCordovaCallback(fn) {
  //Returns a new function 
  return (...opts) => 
    Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
      // This assumes a single call to success will be made
      const nextCallback = (v) => { observer.next(v); observer.complete(); }

      const errCallback = (e) => observer.error(e);

      //Invoke the passed in method.
      fn(nextCallback, errCallback, ...opts);

      //Return empty unless you have some cancellation logic
      return Subscription.EMPTY;
    });
}

const nameObservable = bindCordovaCallback(name)(opts);

//Each subscribe will reinvoke the underlying method just like $http in angular2
nameObservable.subscribe(data => {...}, err => {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One quesiton, how would I pass opts on subscription? currently I'm getting "cannot find name opts" if I call this
const nameObservable = bindCordovaCallback(name)(opts);

Comment: Yes the `opts` parameter needs to be declared. I don't actually know what you will be passing but `bindCOrdovaCallback(name)(opts)` would require the caller to define what options are to be passed in.